# How to build X11 (X Window System) For ARM

Tags: linux, x11, opensuse, xorg

How can I build X11 (X Window System) for ARM CPU in Open-SUSE? 
I used cross-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc for build kernel

Comment: Do you mean the X window system? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

Comment: I've updated your question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'd better use a framework. Check [openebedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) or [yocto](http://www.yoctoproject.org/) or [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/).

I personally use openembedded and I would never ever compile X by hand.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but probably yes. As I told you, I use openembedded, which may be hard to learn, but once you know how to use it you're never going to stop using it.